# Page not found upon jquery request

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I'm trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong here. I have this for my jQuery code and I also have a php controller function called delete that looks like this. Right now when I cxlick on the element with a class of delete it tries to make a request to this page and it can not be found.

```
mysite.com/cms/ctrlpanel/users/delete 

public function delete($user_id)
{
}    

$route['cms/ctrlpanel/users/delete/(:num)'] = 'users/delete/$1';

$('.delete').click(function(e){
    var element = $(this);
    e.preventDefault();
    $.post('/cms/ctrlpanel/users/delete', { 'user_id' : element.attr('rel') }, function(data) 
    {

    ), 'json');
});
```

Comment: It looks like your route is using GET parameters to pass the number, and your jQuery is using POST. So essentially, a number isn't added onto the URL in your $.post request, hence it doesn't match your route.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('.delete').click(function(e){
    var element = $(this).attr('rel');
    e.preventDefault();
    $.post('users/delete/' + element);
});
```

Oops.

```
public function delete($user_id){
    $user_id = (int)$user_id;
```

Comment: One question though it say that when it makes it to my controller function delete the user id is a string. So I'm curious as to what I need to do so that the element is an integer when its sent to the php side. The value that does get passed is '1' instead of 1.

Comment: `var element = +$(this).attr('rel');`

Comment: Can you explain the purpose of the +? Does it turn it into an integer?

Comment: Yep, just shorthand for turning a string to an integer. :)

Comment: I ran this and it came back with number so for some reason its getting to the php side it thinks its a string for some reason. var user_id = parseInt($(this).attr('rel'));
  console.log(jQuery.type( user_id ));